# Tiles taking too long to render

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, osm2pgsql, mod-tile

I've followed the tutorial available [here](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/). The installation worked alright, but opening the tile in a browser leads to a 404 error. The only error from the server is "Failed to read cmd on fd 10".

After a long while, the tile is rendered (here, 1600 seconds):

```
renderd[18586]: DEBUG: DONE TILE default 13 4264-4271 2984-2991 in 1594.968 seconds
debug: Creating and writing a metatile to /var/lib/mod_tile/default/13/0/16/11/170/136.meta
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There really can be many reasons for that. Do your tables have indices built? How long did the second metatile take (DB can take a long time to warm up)? What was IO rate on the server when the tile was being generated? Is the style used the "default" openstreetmap-carto?

Comment: Crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34036/tiles-taking-too-long-to-render

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the settings that are suggested after setting up Postgresql in the link that you followed:

```
shared_buffers = 128MB
checkpoint_segments = 20
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
autovacuum = off
```

Also, please try increasing the number of threads in renderd.conf

And if you are using a relatively common machine eg. 8gb RAM, in my opinion, you should not import the full planet data. Try with small data first.

And the error: "Failed to read cmd on fd 10". Can be ignored.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, with the above settings, and it takes 440s or so to render zoom level 2 tiles.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?